# Entity Framework thread safe create entity if doesn't exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, thread-safety

I'd like to write a method that inserts an entity into my database if it doesn't already exist.  I'd like it to be thread safe across many servers.  So really, it has to be concurrency safe at the database level.  Is this possible with Entity Framework?  Or do I have to do this with raw SQL?

Here's what I have so far:

```
public void CreateFooIfDoesntExist(int bar)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContex())
    {
        if (!dbContext.Set<Foo>().Any(f => f.Bar == bar))
        {
            //Not thread safe because two servers could both fail to find any 
            //Foos at the same time.  Then they'd both try to add a Foo.
            dbContext.Set<Foo>().Add(new Foo { Bar = bar });
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using C# 5.0, EF 5.0 and MSSQL server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a unique index, so the second save will always fail with a well known error code. The catch is, you need a field other than auto-generated ID to create the unique index on.

```
try
{
    using (var context ...) 
    {
        context.Foos.Add(new Foo() { UniqueId = id });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
 catch (UpdateException e) 
 {
     // record with "id" already exists
 }
```

In more complex scenarios you could use database transactions to synchronize multiple processes. When you perform a database update in a transaction with SERIALIZABLE isolation level SQL Server will place a lock on rows that you updated. This lock will prevent any other process not only from writing but even reading data until the first process ends the transaction. So you would essentially have a lock column/row/table in your schema. Whenever you need to perform a global operation you would start a transaction and update the lock, then do any other work you need to perform. No competing process will be able to read/update your lock until the first process ends the transaction.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is this the standard way to do this?  I'd be surprised if EF didn't provide a way that runs the SQL to do this.  And what should I do if the data model shouldn't include a unique constraint on this column?

Comment: If there is no way to uniquely identify the entity you would not worry about inserting duplicate entities, would you? See my expanded answer in the edit.

Comment: You're correct that the more common cases will include unique constraints (including mine).  So this solution works for me.  However, there are certainly reasonable use cases where you'd worry about inserting duplicate entries without being able to set a unique constraint.  One of the more common cases I've seen is when you want to create a row only if there are no matching criteria that have not marked as deleted.  So imagine something like inserting `Foo` only if there are zero `Foos` that have not been marked as deleted by a `dateDeleted` column.

Comment: Isn't it a bit awkward that the best way to do this is to depend on an exception being thrown?